# Как в MySQL сделать запрос к двум (и более) таблицам

Tags: mysql

Понимаю, что это просто, но я только начал учить MySQL

Есть БД "browser", в нем пока две таблицы: "chrome" и "explorer" 
В этих таблицах одинаковые параметры "years" и "values"

"years" - года / "values" - статистики использования (максимальная).

[image: Структура БД]

Вот так все выглядит у меня

Нужно для каждого браузера определить год, в котором значение статистики использования максимальная.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать запрос к двум столбцам
Заранее всем спасибо

Comment: что за данные зраняться в `values`?

Comment: @ПростаMiha числа с фиксированной точкой типа (longtext)

Comment: select 'chrome' as browser, years from chrome order by values desc limit 1
union
select 'explorer' as browser, years from explorer order by values desc limit 1

Comment: это не нормально разбивать одинаковые данные на 2 таблицы в данном случае. так же не нормально хранить число в фиксированной точки в виде longtext